# Lua Check for Value Against Array Elements

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

Trying to teach myself Lua; I've gone through similar questions about this, and I still can't understand how to do this. The main thing that is confusing me is tables vs arrays. For the below code I'm just wanting check a given value against values I've populated into an array. However, something is going wrong. Thank for your time.

```
valueToCheckFor = 35    

sampleArray = {}
for i=30, 49, 1  do
  sampleArray[i] = i + 1
  print(i)
end    

for k = 0, #sampleArray, 1 do
    if valueToCheckFor == k then
        print(valueToCheckFor .. " is in the array.")
    else
        print(valueToCheckFor .. " is not in the array.")
    end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for an item in a Lua list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656199/search-for-an-item-in-a-lua-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code written to be Lua array friendly:

```
valueToCheckFor = 35

sampleArray = {}
for i=30, 49  do
    -- add to end of array
    sampleArray[#sampleArray+1] = i + 1
    print(i+1)
end

-- check each value in array
for k = 1, #sampleArray do
    if valueToCheckFor == sampleArray[k] then
        print(valueToCheckFor .. " is in the array.")
    else
        print(valueToCheckFor .. " is not in the array.")
    end
end
```

Comment: @babyy on SO people aim to always backup their statements, that's how we all learn from each other. Truth is I don't see anything wrong with the stated soln, except that author should have explained what was wrong (which other answers have done, but they didn't provide fix).

Answer (score 1):

You `sampleArray` is not  a *sequence* because does not begin at 1 and so `#` cannot be used on it. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

`#sampleArray` return `0` because your array is not started by `1`

> The array part is every key that starts with the number 1 and
>   increases up until the first value that is nil

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613573/1198482