# why are there no objects added to my table

Tags: arrays, lua

I'm working on a lua script where I need a list of buttons to display. I have the following method to add a button to the list `buttons`:

```
function addButton(name, text, func, activeColor, passiveColor, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, type)
    buttons[name] = {}
    buttons[name]["text"] = text
    buttons[name]["func"] = func
    buttons[name]["active"] = false
    buttons[name]["activeColor"]  = getColorOrDefault(activeColor, ACTIVECOLORDEFAULT)
    buttons[name]["passiveColor"] = getColorOrDefault(passiveColor, PASSIVECOLORDEFAULT)
    buttons[name]["xmin"] = xmin
    buttons[name]["xmax"] = xmax
    buttons[name]["ymin"] = ymin
    buttons[name]["ymax"] = ymax
    buttons[name]["type"] = type
    print("added: "..table.getn(buttons))
end
```

This function is called twice to add 2 buttons, but the output is:

> added: 0 
> added: 0

what could be a reason my elements are not added to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're being added--You're just using the wrong method to detect them.

As you can read about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613322/lua-table-getn-returns-0), using `table.getn` only returns the amount of array slots (numeric indexes, such as `buttons[0]` or `buttons[23]`. Note that this only counts as an array slot if there are no null indexes in between `buttons[1]` and `buttons[23]`!

Using this debugging code, we'll see that your items are indeed being added to the buttons table:

```lua
for name, button in pairs(buttons) do
    print(name, button)
end
```

This is also how you'd get a list of your buttons :-)